# bold table column in latex beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I'm trying to bold a single column of a table inside latex beamer.
in latex i used

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|>{\bfseries}c|c|}
```

for example, to make the 4th column bold.
in beamer, the bfseries macro does not apply. anyone knows why ?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me this works. Maybe you forgot to load `array`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme[mathserif]{serif}
\usecolortheme[RGB={100,45,10}]{structure}
\beamertemplatesolidbackgroundcolor{yellow!10}
\beamertemplatetransparentcoveredmedium
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Seite 1}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc>{\bfseries}cc}
    a &a & a& a &a\\
    a &a & a& a &a\\
    a &a & a& a &a
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]